# How do I make adbd transport to listen on a tcp port in android emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I want to connect to adb shell from my app. To achieve it I need adbd transport to listen on a tcp port.

Using a real device is not a solution, I want to test my app specifically with android emulator.

I create and run the emulator:

```
avdmanager create avd -n phone -d pixel_xl  -k "system-images;android-30;google_apis_playstore;x86_64"
emulator @phone
```

I run `adb tcpip 5555`. Though the command runs successfully adbd transport is not exposed.

###### `adb shell logcat | grep adbd`

```
01-15 15:40:23.786  2013  2013 I adbd    : Setup mdns on port= 5555
01-15 15:40:23.787  2013  2032 I adbd    : Waiting for persist.adb.tls_server.enable=1
01-15 15:40:23.787  2013  2013 I adbd    : adbd listening on tcp:5555
01-15 15:40:23.788  2013  2013 I adbd    : adbd listening on vsock:5555
01-15 15:40:23.798  2013  2040 I adbd    : host-14: read thread spawning
01-15 15:40:23.799  2013  2013 I adbd    : host-14: already offline
01-15 15:40:23.799  2013  2013 I adbd    : Calling send_auth_request...
01-15 15:40:23.806  2013  2041 I adbd    : host-14: write thread spawning
01-15 15:40:23.808  2013  2013 I adbd    : adbd_auth: loading keys from /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
01-15 15:40:23.809  2013  2013 I adbd    : adb client authorized
01-15 15:40:23.818  2013  2033 I adbd    : adbd_auth: received a new framework connection
01-15 15:40:23.819  2013  2033 I adbd    : adbd_auth: received new framework fd 18 (current = -1)
01-15 15:40:23.819  2013  2033 I adbd    : adbd_auth: marking framework writable
01-15 15:40:24.793  2013  2034 I adbd    : adbd mDNS service _adb._tcp registered: 1
01-15 15:43:09.598  2013  6477 I adbd    : adbd restarting in TCP mode (port = 5555)
01-15 15:43:09.635  6478  6479 I adbd    : Waiting for persist.adb.tls_server.enable=1
01-15 15:43:09.635  6478  6478 I adbd    : Setup mdns on port= 5555
01-15 15:43:09.635  6478  6478 I adbd    : adbd listening on tcp:5555
01-15 15:43:09.635  6478  6478 I adbd    : adbd listening on vsock:5555
01-15 15:43:09.635  6478  6481 I adbd    : adbd mDNS service _adb._tcp registered: 1
01-15 15:43:10.856  6478  6485 I adbd    : host-12: read thread spawning
01-15 15:43:10.856  6478  6486 I adbd    : host-12: write thread spawning
01-15 15:43:10.857  6478  6478 I adbd    : host-12: already offline
01-15 15:43:10.857  6478  6478 I adbd    : Calling send_auth_request...
01-15 15:43:10.859  6478  6478 I adbd    : adbd_auth: loading keys from /data/misc/adb/adb_keys
01-15 15:43:10.860  6478  6478 I adbd    : adb client authorized
01-15 15:43:11.607  6478  6480 I adbd    : adbd_auth: received a new framework connection
01-15 15:43:11.607  6478  6480 I adbd    : adbd_auth: received new framework fd 18 (current = -1)
01-15 15:43:11.607  6478  6480 I adbd    : adbd_auth: marking framework writable
```

###### `adb shell netstat -tulpn`

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program Name
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.16:54912         172.217.16.42:443       ESTABLISHED -
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.16:60088         172.217.20.202:443      ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:43504  ::ffff:142.250.75.3:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:43502  ::ffff:142.250.75.3:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:44476  ::ffff:64.233.164.:5228 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:59130  ::ffff:142.250.203.:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:50832  ::ffff:172.217.16.1:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:50836  ::ffff:172.217.16.1:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:35828  ::ffff:216.58.215.1:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:48984  ::ffff:216.58.215.7:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:49628  ::ffff:172.217.16.4:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:60070  ::ffff:172.217.20.2:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:43942  ::ffff:216.58.215.6:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:57422  ::ffff:142.250.203.:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:54880  ::ffff:172.217.16.4:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:54876  ::ffff:172.217.16.4:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:43506  ::ffff:142.250.75.3:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:60054  ::ffff:172.217.20.2:443 ESTABLISHED -
tcp6       0      0 ::ffff:10.0.2.16:60072  ::ffff:172.217.20.2:443 ESTABLISHED -
udp     4608      0 10.0.2.16:68            10.0.2.2:67             ESTABLISHED -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50490           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp6       0      0 :::35263                :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::5228                 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                -
```

###### `adb shell nc localhost 5555`

```
nc: connect: Connection refused
```

I also tried using different system image with no success:

```
avdmanager create avd -n tv -d tv_720p -k "system-images;android-28;android-tv;x86"
```

How do I make it possible to connect to emulator adb shell using tcp transport?

Comment: Have you tried `adb forward` (forward the adb TCP port to the emulator)?

Comment: @Robert I have tried `adb forward`. It is redundant though since I cannot connect to the port inside the device shell.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Using adb shell from within an app is something that will never really work outside of a very special set-up.

Comment: @Robert It is an actual working method to simulate HID device on android tv without root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no supported way to do this. When in emulator(`ro.kernel.qemu=1`) adb uses QEMUD pipes instead of regular sockets.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r61/adb/transport_local.cpp#388

#### EDIT

I made it work.
I replaced

```
func = use_qemu_goldfish() ? qemu_socket_thread : server_socket_thread;
```

with

```
std::thread(qemu_socket_thread, port).detach();
std::thread(server_socket_thread, port).detach();
```

For some reason adb doesn't work if you run only `server_socket_thread`.